# Illustrator select--> same--> colour option not selecting live paint object

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am making small balloon artwork in latest Adobe Illustrator 2020 by following a book.

In that

1. Balloon is the live paint object and
2. Balloon's basket is made of individual shapes (Not a group or compound object).

All the objects have same stroke colour (Black RGB(29,29,27)) and width (10pt).(Checked that twice)

When I am using Select --> Same --> Stroke colour, Illustrator is selecting everything except Live paint object.

I don't understand why. Does somebody know if it doesn't work with Live paint objects ?

I can share more information as reuired.

Comment: Because the live paint object is a special kind of object. Understanding your object types and effect stacks is important in vector graphics. Vector graphics is about what is not what seems to be. If you expand it then sure go ahead then its a normal obhect. Personally i feel like one should not use live paint objects, except in specialized workflows, but use shapebuilding instead.

Comment: Thanks @joojaa. I didn't quite get this line : "Vector graphics is about what is not what seems to be".

BTW,  I got my answer. Thanks again.

Comment: A vector drawing is a modeling system. Not a drawing, not an image. It models a graphic, but thats not what it is. If you can control your design to the level of all individual elements then you will succeed in circumventing a lot of problems without needing to think about them.